# Can a US Citizen fly from Tijuana to Mexico City with a California ID?

Tags: air-travel, us-citizens, mexico, identity-cards

Will I be allowed to board the plane with just my state ID?

Comment: Do you have a residence permit or visa for Mexico?  If not, do you have a *Forma Migratoria Múltiple* (FMM)?  You need to have one of those to leave the border area, and you need to show your US passport to get the FMM.  I don't know whether an airline would enforce that, but if you don't have an FMM, a visa, or a residence permit then you shouldn't fly to Mexico City, and if you don't have a US passport, you cannot get an FMM.

Comment: I went earlier this year in May with a passport, but did not get a FMM. They never asked for one. I know my passport number but don’t have my passport because I sent it to the passport agency 4 weeks ago to renew it & somehow they still don’t receive my documents. That is why I’m going to attempt to use my state ID.

Comment: Yes, US Passport required to Travel Mexico City.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Mexico City's airport website](https://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs), foreigners are required to present their passports when traveling on domestic flights, so the answer is **no** - you will not be allowed to board with just your driving license.